# Mongoid Habtm relationship with specified class_name

Tags: mongoid

I have two very simple classes:

```
class Contact
  include Mongoid::Document     
  has_and_belongs_to_many :organizations, :class_name => 'Organization'     
end
```

and

```
class Organization
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_and_belongs_to_many  :relations, :class_name => 'Contact'
end
```

and here is the error log upon validating / saving:

```
>> org = Organization.new
#<Organization _id: 5228ae3c1d41c8678c000001, relation_ids: nil, _type: "Organization">

>> org.valid?
org.valid?
NoMethodError: undefined method `has_key?' for #<Mongoid::Criteria:0x00000008d32bd0>
    from /home/muichkine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bundler/gems/mongoid-38de2e96edc8/lib/mongoid/criteria.rb:501:in `method_missing'
    from /home/muichkine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bundler/gems/mongoid-38de2e96edc8/lib/mongoid/relations/referenced/many.rb:413:in `block in method_missing'
    from /home/muichkine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bundler/gems/mongoid-38de2e96edc8/lib/mongoid/scopable.rb:238:in `with_scope'
    from /home/muichkine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bundler/gems/mongoid-38de2e96edc8/lib/mongoid/relations/referenced/many.rb:412:in `method_missing'
    from /home/muichkine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bundler/gems/mongoid-38de2e96edc8/lib/mongoid/validatable.rb:72:in `read_attribute_for_validation'
    from /home/muichkine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activemodel-4.0.0/lib/active_model/validator.rb:151:in `block in validate'
    from /home/muichkine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activemodel-4.0.0/lib/active_model/validator.rb:150:in `each'
    from /home/muichkine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activemodel-4.0.0/lib/active_model/validator.rb:150:in `validate'
    from /home/muichkine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:283:in `_callback_before_145'
    from /home/muichkine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:377:in `_run__4324115989737504907__validate__callbacks'
    from /home/muichkine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
    from /home/muichkine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bundler/gems/mongoid-38de2e96edc8/lib/mongoid/interceptable.rb:132:in `run_callbacks'
    from /home/muichkine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activemodel-4.0.0/lib/active_model/validations.rb:373:in `run_validations!'
    from /home/muichkine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activemodel-4.0.0/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:106:in `block in run_validations!'
    from /home/muichkine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__4324115989737504907__validation__callbacks'
    from /home/muichkine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
    from /home/muichkine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bundler/gems/mongoid-38de2e96edc8/lib/mongoid/interceptable.rb:132:in `run_callbacks'
    from /home/muichkine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activemodel-4.0.0/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:106:in `run_validations!'
    from /home/muichkine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activemodel-4.0.0/lib/active_model/validations.rb:314:in `valid?'
    from /home/muichkine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bundler/gems/mongoid-38de2e96edc8/lib/mongoid/validatable.rb:98:in `valid?'
    from (irb):3
    from /home/muichkine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /home/muichkine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /home/muichkine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/muichkine/src/white/bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from /home/muichkine/src/white/bin/rails:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
>> contact = Contact.new
contact = Contact.new
#<Contact _id: 5228ae441d41c8678c000002, organization_ids: nil, _type: "Contact">

>> contact.valid?
true
```

as you can see, validating a Contact works while validating an Organization does not. Now, I did try to add `:inverse_of` options on both sides but the error remains. Any input is appreciated.

I use:
    mongoid (4.0.0 38de2e9) with Rails 4 / Ruby 2.0.0-p247

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem is the name of the second `has_and_belongs_to_many` . If you change it to anything else it should work. Anyways thats a short solution for you, you should also file a issue on [monogid](http://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/new), about that situation. I am pretty much sure this is happening because relations is a internal method on the Mongoid Document.

Comment: That struck me right after leaving my desk as the only possibility left!..And it is, just changed the name and it works. Thanks Arthur.